# How to save libsvm predicted class labels to csv?

Tags: csv, libsvm

I am new to SVM and I'm using libsvm 3.21 to train and test my data. I have class labels 1,2,..,5 for each of my instances (let's say I have 10).

Is there a way to print the predicted class labels (e.g. 3,5,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,4) to a csv or txt file? I've been looking here http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html, but it seems that libsvm only outputs this (along with the .model, .range, and .scale files):

```
optimization finished, #iter = 219
nu = 0.431030
obj = -100.877286, rho = 0.424632
nSV = 132, nBSV = 107
Total nSV = 132
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the README in libsvm, say you have train.data, test.data, what you need to do is train your data using svm-train

```
user:~$ ./svm-train train.data svm.model
*
optimization finished, #iter = 162
nu = 0.431029
obj = -100.877288, rho = 0.424462
nSV = 132, nBSV = 107
Total nSV = 132
```

and then test your test.data using the model you just trained using svm-predict

```
user:~$ ./svm-predict test.data svm.model svm.output
Accuracy = 86.6667% (234/270) (classification)
```

And you can find your predicted label in svm.output.

```
user:~$ head -5 svm.output 
1
-1
-1
1
-1
```

In particular, if you want to change it to .csv file, you can type

```
user:~$ tr -s '\n' ',' < svm.output > svm.csv
```